# XML Serialization in SSIS

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, ssis

**I am using this code to serialize a object to XML in a SSIS package :**

```
    public String SerializeObject<T>(T piObj)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();

            xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, piObj);
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            return exc.Message + Environment.NewLine + exc.InnerException.Message +
                Environment.NewLine + exc.Source + Environment.NewLine + exc.StackTrace
                + Environment.NewLine + exc.TargetSite
                + Environment.NewLine + exc.InnerException.InnerException
                + Environment.NewLine + exc.InnerException.StackTrace;
        }
    }
```

**But I get this Error:**

> *Failed to generate the XML document. An exception occurred on the typeinitiator*
>
> Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterList1.
>   System.Xml    vid
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter,
>   Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle,
>   String id)    vid
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter
>   textWriter, Object o)    vid
>   ExportPurchases.SerializeUtilities.SerializeObject[T](T piObj) Void
>   Serialize(System.Xml.XmlWriter, System.Object,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces, System.String,
>   System.String)
>
> *System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*
>
> vid
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterList1..cctor()
>   vid
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterList1..ctor()
>   vid
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializerContract.get_Writer()
>   vid System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.InvokeWriter(XmlMapping
>   mapping, XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces
>   namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)    vid
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter,
>   Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle,
>   String id)

Comment: What do you think the problem is?

Comment: so far it's look like that you can not serialize generic list<T> in SSIS script. This code works with generic array only.

Comment: That'snot the problem - you can serialise a Generic List. However there is no guarantee that the T involved is serialisable. Can you post the code for the types?